# Python: How to include \r in print output?

Tags: python

How can I format my string such that `\r` is included in the output rather than being interpreted as a carriage return?

I am building a long string with formatting entities in it like `\n` and `\t`, hence I want to preserve the printing output that I get with the below.

```
s1 = ("""
        WITH (
            DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureStorage',
            FORMAT = 'CSV',
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
            DATAFILETYPE='char',
            ROWTERMINATOR='\r',
            TABLOCK)
            """)
print(''.join(s1))
```

Comment: You want two characters, a backslash and then `r`? Then you want `'\\r'`.

Comment: try `print(repr(''.join(s1)))` or just `print(repr(s1))` as join is useless here

Comment: @CharlesDuffy has a good answer, but as an alternative, you can make it a raw string:  `s1 = (r"""`.

Comment: BTW, your `join` is useless.  I'm not sure what you were expecting, but `s1` is already a string.  There's nothing to join.

Comment: Thanks -- all great help!

Comment: You can read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) to know more about raw strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use repr function it returns a string containing a printable representation of an object.

```
s1 = ("""
        WITH (
            DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureStorage',
            FORMAT = 'CSV',
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
            DATAFILETYPE='char',
            ROWTERMINATOR='\r',
            TABLOCK)
            """)
print(repr(s1))
```

Or use additional backward slash

```
ROWTERMINATOR='\\r',
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an r-string:

```py
s1 = r"""
        WITH (
            DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureStorage',
            FORMAT = 'CSV',
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
            DATAFILETYPE='char',
            ROWTERMINATOR='\r',
            TABLOCK)
"""
print(''.join(s1))
```